# Is foreach java loop able to modify a set collection?

Tags: java

I have a **set** collection which I would like to **only read** in order to compare values, the problem is that I get a **java.util.ConcurrentModificationException** but I am not changing set elements.

```
            Set<eu.datex2.schema._2_0._2_3.SituationRecord> setSituation = map.keySet();

            for (SituationRecord situationRecord : situationRecordList) {
                String implementedSituationTRecordClass = situationRecord.getClass().toString().substring(32);
                synchronized (setSituation) {
                    //The problem is in the next line
                    for (eu.datex2.schema._2_0._2_3.SituationRecord situ : setSituation) {
                        if (Objects.equals(situ.getId(), situationRecord.getId())) {//Comparamos si ya existe en el mapa
                            System.out.println("ID from map: " + situ.getId() + "ID from datex1: " + situationRecord.getId());
                            situationRecordList2.add(situ);
                            flagSituatinNoEncontrado.setValor(false);
                        }
                        if (flagSituatinNoEncontrado.isValor()) {
                            System.out.println("CREA");
                            situationRecordList2 = giveMeAsituationRecord2List(situationRecordList2, implementedSituationTRecordClass, situationRecord, global, uniqe, map, latitude, longitude, delta, areaAdministracion, numCarretera);
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

        }
```

Comment: On which line does this exception occur?

Comment: for (eu.datex2.schema._2_0._2_3.SituationRecord situ : setSituation) {                                                                                                                     Is like an Iterator.next(), this rises me a Concurrent Exception

Comment: Are you sure you can't use a for loop or something else than a foreach?

Comment: The question is what I can not iterate over a set that I am only reading

Comment: It won't give this error if you're only reading, it writes behind the scene apparently. Try iterating over it in a way that allows writing, it will solve your problem.

Comment: can you post the code for `giveMeAsituationRecord2List()`

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're changing `map` somewhere in your code. Either in `giveMeAsituationRecord2List` or in another thread.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the problem iterating over a list instead of a set, but I continue to not understand why you can not iterate over a set of abstract class.

```
Set<eu.datex2.schema._2_0._2_3.SituationRecord> setSituation = Collections.synchronizedSet(map.keySet());
List<eu.datex2.schema._2_0._2_3.SituationRecord> list = Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList<>());
list.addAll(setSituation);
```